# Spring Data Cassandra issue when trying to connect from another Spring app configuration/Context

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Here are versions we use in our project:

```
<spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-data-cassandra>1.1.0.RELEASE</spring-data-cassandra>
```

I am getting this error when trying to connect from another Spring app configuration/Context.

```
Oct 25, 2014 11:17:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.getProperty(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;] with root cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.getProperty(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:244)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:261)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInsertFromWrapper(MappingCassandraConverter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInsertFromObject(MappingCassandraConverter.java:233)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:222)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.createInsertQuery(CassandraTemplate.java:638)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:526)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:59)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed JPA version of parent POM from 1.5.2.RELEASE to latest 1.7.0.RELEASE

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to spring-data-cassandra-1.1.1.RELEASE. This has the fix